How can I repeat first row and first column of a table in LaTeX output in Quarto in R?
I am using Quarto in R to prepare a LaTeX/PDF output. In this document, I have a table, which is quite wide and long (13 columns and 70 rows). The first row contains the column names, and the first column contains the row names. I want these names to appear throughout the pages in which this table is printed. How can I do this?
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100),
                 b = rnorm(100),
                 c = rnorm(100),
                 d = rnorm(100),
                 e = rnorm(100),
                 f = rnorm(100),
                 g = rnorm(100),
                 h = rnorm(100),
                 i = rnorm(100))
kbl(df,longtable = TRUE,booktabs = TRUE)

For short tables, the kbl function gives the look that I want. But for this table, I suspect I am missing some option, or probably I need some other package. Can someone help me with this?

Have you tried kable_styling(latex_options = "repeat_header")?

Yes, the "repeat_header" option repeats the first row on each page, but the last few columns don't get printed even after using "repeat_header".

maybe add option scale_down to latex options.

Also you can use the fontsize argument in kable_styling to reduce the font size for the table.
